# Android Studio 2.2 frequently crashes on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, java, android-studio

I was using Android Studio on my Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. That worked fine.  Recently I installed Ubuntu 16.04 64bit, and I also installed Android Studio 2.2 on my PC. But my Android Studio crashes frequently. It closes instantly.

My java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

Also I created `$JAVA_HOME` variable. I set right jdk location in my Studio.  But it frequently crashes. Here with I have attached Studio error report.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff6aba86384, pid=3955, tid=0x00007ff684e6d700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_76-b03) (build 1.8.0_76-release-b03)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.76-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x895384]  PhaseCCP::analyze()+0x274
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007ff6a40fa800):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3968, stack(0x00007ff684d6d000,0x00007ff684e6e000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 128 (SI_KERNEL), si_addr: 0x0000000000000000...
```

I don't know why this problem occurs. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you solve this problem ? I am facing the same issue now

Comment: No @MithunSarkerShuvro.. Still I am facing same problem..  I raised bug report in google issue list..

Comment: I am also facing same issue :(

Comment: @TirthPatel, I posted an answer. Check it once below.

Answer (score 0):

as I see you're trying to run Android Studio using Java SE. PLease install `Oracle Java 8 Java Development Kit (JDK)` and set it in `Android Studio` using `File_>Project Structure`.

Comment: Hi Piotrek1543! I think I already installed Java jdk before installing Android Studio using this command.  
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer.  If something missing, then how to I install Java 8 JDK?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem in my Ubuntu 16.04, with Android Studio 2.2.3 installed. What I did is a simple trick.

Goto your home directory.

```
home/<your_name>
```

And hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>H</kbd> . Now this will display the hidden directories inside your home directory. Find out `.android` [dot android] and delete it. You can keep backup and then delete the directory.

This process remove the old cache of Android Studio. Now start your Android Studio, the IDE automatically creates `.android` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You did not include the entire Studio crash log file.
But if your log contains something that looks similiar to:

`Stack: [0x00007ff49571f000,0x00007ff495820000],  sp=0x00007ff49581ca00,  free space=1014k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libX11.so.6+0x4a949]  XSetICValues+0xf9
j  sun.awt.X11.XInputMethod.setXICFocusNative(JZZ)V+0
j  sun.awt.X11.XInputMethod.setXICFocus(Ljava/awt/peer/ComponentPeer;ZZ)V+25
j  sun.awt.X11InputMethod.activate()V+162
j  sun.awt.im.InputContext.activateInputMethod(Z)V+169
j  sun.awt.im.InputContext.focusGained(Ljava/awt/Component;)V+137
J 45972 C2 sun.awt.im.InputMethodContext.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V (62 bytes) @ 0x00007ff502eabc48 [0x00007ff502eab8e0+0x368]
J 72758 C1 java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V (883 bytes) @ 0x00007ff50746da94 [0x00007ff50746a4e0+0x35b4]
J 21802 C2 java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V (129 bytes) @ 0x00007ff4ff1e6934 [0x00007ff4ff1e68e0+0x54]
J 40400 C1 java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Ljava/awt/Component;Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)Z (352 bytes) @ 0x00007ff5020f87dc [0x00007ff5020f6820+0x1fbc]
J 72166 C2 java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)Z (1589 bytes) @ 0x00007ff503c34a68 [0x00007ff503c325e0+0x2488]`

Then you are most likely having issues due to known, long standing bug with AS (and IntelliJ) and iBus [as documented here by Google](http://tools.android.com/knownissues/ibus).

As per that page, what I found works best for me is:

> Workaround #2: Disable IBus input in Studio
>
> $ XMODIFIERS= ./bin/studio.sh

Comment: Hi! Where I find Android Studio crash log files, you have mentioned it.  Please comment.

Comment: The crash log files are in your home folder usually.

Comment: Still I am facing this issue.  This is my log files https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YSbmYo7TSHZoLs5MgVTEiNaa1vPoo5lF.  Please help me to fix Android Studio issues.

Comment: Sorry all I can say is what worked for me based on the recommendation in the Android Studio documentation.